# Cant install GPUImage framework - GPUImage.h not found

Tags: static-libraries, gpuimage

i have an app and i want to install GPUImage framework. I did following steps:

1) Adding project to my app. I did following > XCode->Add Files-> then choose GPUImage.xcodeproj, and select "copy items to destination project"

2) Now it says : `Next, go to your application's target and add GPUImage as a Target Dependency`. Im not really sure how to achieve that, what i did is - in product->Scheme->Edit scheme i add GPUImage.

3) I add libGPUImage.a to Build Phases -> Link binary with Libraries

4) I tried every solution i had found to finally add full path of GPUImage.xcodeproj to header search path. Nothing work at all. There is a warning - GPUImage.h not found. I had tried many ways to add full path here, everything i did found concerning this error, but still, there is an error.

How could i fix that? Maybe i made mistakes in previous steps? I really wonder how i manage to spend many hours just trying to add framework to my app, and still unsuccessfully..

Answer (score 1):

This is what's meant by adding a framework as a target dependency:

[image: Target dependency image]

Those are all under your project settings. You shouldn't need to do anything with your scheme.

As far as the header file goes, you have to make sure your Header Search Paths are set correctly in your Build Settings. If you look at the sample applications that ship with the project, they have that set to `../../../framework` (with the recursive search box checked), which is the relative path to the framework from their project directories.

You need to find what this path is for your application project relative to where you placed the GPUImage source.